# Python libraray "Flask" not found

Tags: python, flask, pip, environment

I am using MacOS and trying HelloWorld for Flask.

Created a Virtual Environment for Flask and sourced it:

```
source ./venv_flask/bin/activate
```

Installed flask with `pip install flask` and checked:
~/python/venv_flask » pip freeze

```
click==6.6
Flask==0.11.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
python-dateutil==2.5.3
requests==2.10.0
six==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.11.10
```

Created very simple (1 line) python file:
~/python/venv_flask » cat hello.py

```
from flask import Flask
```

When try to run it - error show up:
~/python/venv_flask » python hello.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/Users/user1/python/venv_flask/flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for
ImportError: cannot import name Flask
```

How to properly install/run python code with Fask application?

Comment: You have a file named `flask.py`. It's clearly visible in your traceback. Remove it or rename it, and the problem will go away

Comment: Move `Users/user1/python/venv_flask/flask.py` aside, it is masking the library.